# Fronting correct use

Tags: word-order, speech, subject-verb-inversion, fronting

I have this phrase (created myself)

> He was entering into the office slowly / Slowly, he was entering into the office.

(there shouldn't be difference I suppose)

Now, the rules say that if I have an adverbial phrase of place or movement, it should be placed at the beginning when fronting.

- My question is: Having both an adverbial phrase of place and an adverb, may I say

> *Slowly, into the office was he entering*
>   OR
>   *Into the office, slowly, was he entering*

- One more question: is fronting (like negative inversion) and the abovementioned "case" used in speech? If yes, is it used only in formal speech?

Comment: Please note: This does not answer your question, but pl. note that when 'enter' is used with a place, there is no need to say 'enter into' as in 'they **entered** the cafe,' 'he **entered** the office.' The use of 'enter into' is more appropriate for situations like 'they **entered into** a marriage / contract / agreement' 'he entered into a long course of study' etc.

Comment: Thanks. WIth reference to ur correction, is there any way to know which preposition each word takes? (like Believe IN)

Comment: Sorry to say that English is not so easy to work out by *rules!* I was just giving you the *convention of usage* regarding 'enter.' Similarly 'believe' or 'believe in' applied in the same sentence can make a big difference in the meaning, as in 'I believe him' and 'I believe **in** him' -- it is not about *rule* but about *context* -- simply by READING A LOT of good English from varied sources, (I could, and) you can learn how to use the right expression in the right place!

Comment: Never did I think of this difference between believe and believe in  in a context, but I do see the meaning of each one. Anyway, I had doubts on this matter, as I've been studying for CAE, using a CAE/CPE book, which is well provided with lots of information. The drawback of this fact is that there are many things such as fronting that may be constructed in several ways and be used with other "rules". I don't know if I made my point clear. What I meant is that in a certain way when we begin a sentence with a that clause ( That I hate you is true) is fronting but on my book, it's badlyexplained

Comment: Your problem is well addressed by the kind member Chaim in the first answer. As I said, learning English is a long and intuitive process where rule books serve only as a 'guide' -- the encouraging thing for you is that English is very flexible and accommodates a wide variety of unconventional usages. I AM SURE you will improve very quickly as you become very familiar with the language through wide reading!

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with that comment of English Student: "enter a room" does not require "into." That's a point about syntax. But I think that your question was not about the syntax of "enter," but about the word order in some comparable situation, with a verb that would take a preposition.

Your sentences sound strange to me. I think that the most natural order (without fronting) would be "He entered the office slowly." Next, for emphasis, "Slowly he entered the office."

Those would be possible with a verb like "walked," which would take a preposition in this context. In such a case there would be three expressions to order: (1) He walked (2) into the office (3) slowly.

I think the natural orders (without fronting) would include.

- He walked into the office slowly.
- He walked slowly into the office.

Next in terms of naturalness, I think, you could say:

- Slowly he walked into the office.

Remaining arrangements don't sound to me like native syntax:

- Into the office he walked slowly.
- Slowly into the office he walked.
- Into the office slowly he walked.

I think that if I read one of those last examples I would assume that the author was not a native speaker, or that he was trying to produce some sort of literary effect.

Comment: Thanks fou your replying. Well, on my book it's said that a phrase like "He jumped out of the water" could be transformed in this way "Out of the wated he jumped" .     Then, there's another example where it's demonstrated how to "front" an adverbial phrase.    This is the phrase   "They walked slowly into the garden."         and it becomes --> "Slowly, they walked into the garden.

Comment: I was wondering how I should use fronting when in my phrase there's the verb "be" plus an adverb.

Comment: Very nice answer to a rather difficult question!

Comment: Like "I was slowly coming to the party. ( what's the difference between this and Slowly, I was..." ( is it just a matter of emphasis?   Anyway   may this phrase be transformed into   Slowly, to the party was I coming    or something like "Slowly, to the party I was coming  ??   I m writing properly but I'm in a hurry.  Anyway, I hope u got my point

Comment: Last but not least, on my book it's reported that when we have be as final verb in a fronted (?) phrase, it should be placed in front of the subject  like    I was guilty --> Guilty Was I... so my question, (despite having written lots of words) is:  May I use this "rule" ( the verb be before the subject together with the rule used in the abovementioned comment, where I put slowly at the beginning?   I expressed myself badly and I'm sorry for that

Comment: @FrancisRickOnorato As Chaim says in the answer "...not a native speaker, or that he was trying to produce some sort of literary effect" -- I am not a native speaker of English myself, but native speakers rarely 'front' a sentence with an adverb such as 'slowly' -- that's why it sounds strange. Such sentences are seen more often in literary writing such as stories and novels; as in 'slowly,  he picked up the letters scattered on the floor, and carried them into his office' where it is indeed a matter of emphasis or a more expressive way of writing.

Comment: One more question :   Could I use fronting in essays, proposal or something alike to these examples?  I ask this because I see the concept but I don't know firstly whether or not it is formal and,consequently, If it could be correct in essays.

Comment: I assume the same concept applys to fronting example like    "That we don't care is true" and other kinds of fronting such as negative inversion. Thereotically, I could emphasise something in essays, couldn't I?

Comment: @FrancisRickOnorato in short, such constructions are old fashioned and literary (as seen in some very old English poems, plays and early novels) but sound irregular to the modern reader in most contexts; so you are advised to *avoid* such sentences unless you are **absolutely sure** their use in the specific situation is appropriate! WHEN IN DOUBT, DON'T USE.

Comment: You forgot one very common and natural-sounding order: “He slowly walked into the office”. Also the last three (and various permutations of them) are definitely native—they're just limited to particular contexts. I'd be very surprised to hear anyone utter them in natural conversation, but I wouldn't bat an eye if I saw or heard them in a poem or a song lyric.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I agree with all of that. The question was about fronting, so I omitted arrangements added by interposing the adverb "slowly" into the clause "He walked," because that doesn't seem like fronting to me. I agree that some unusual constructions would be suitable in songs or poems; I would consider that a literary effect.

Comment: "Out of the water he jumped" may be grammatical, but it is very, very odd.

Comment: @JeffMorrow It’s not odd at all, just—as the answer says—a literary effect. Imagine reading this in a children’s novel: “The bird spread its enormous wings, and WHOOSH, into the air it rose with a mighty flapping that nearly knocked Jim off his feet.” Perfectly natural and normal.

Comment: @FrancisRickOnorato I just saw your first comment now. A very important distinction that it seems your book does not make is that “Slowly, he entered the room” **is not fronting**. It is a completely different kettle of fish. Any adverbial constituent which modifies the main verb in a sentence can be moved _out_ of its clause entirely and put at the head of the sentence. When you do that, it is no longer part of the clause at all, so all rules that apply to fronting become irrelevant. Adverbial extrapolation is **very common**, while fronting is reasonably uncommon (except mandatory types).

Comment: @Jacquet Please give me an actual example from a published work by a native speaker of adverb, prepositional phrase, inverted progressive verb. There may be examples, but I still believe the construction is quite rare. I do not believe any native speaker would write "slowly, into the office, he was entering" or "into the office, slowly he was entering."  A native speaker might well write "slowly, he was entering into the office" or, for effect, "into the office, he was slowly entering." Frankly, even the latter sounds strained to me.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I must have missed your comment in December. The crux here is _progressive_ verb. Fronted PP does indeed sound highly unusual and very, very rare to me with a progressive verb, too—I can’t think of any natural-sounding examples either. But with simple present forms (which all the examples in the answer and your first comment were) it sounds perfectly normal to me, if a bit literary or precious.

Comment: @JBH I do not think we seriously disagree. The original question involved a progressive verb form. I should have stuck with that question and not been distracted by the drift in comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really good reason to say "He was entering [into] the office....", I wouldn't recommend it.  The verb form "...was entering..." might be OK in some cases, but in this case I think the ordinary past tense ("...entered...") would be better.  And there's also the problem of "into".  You see, "enter into an office" normally means "take on the position or rank".  When a successful candidate is inaugurated, he or she enters into the office or position of [whatever: President, chairman, archbishop, etc].  I don't think this is what you meant.  Instead, I assume you mean "enter the office", which normally means "go into the office, i.e., the room where business takes place".  I recommend, then, that you say "He entered the office..." and omit the "into".   Be that as it may, let's take your originals:

1. *He was entering into the office slowly.*  This sentence is OK, but, as I mentioned above, I would omit "into". Try *He entered the office slowly* or *He slowly entered the office*.
2. *Slowly, he was entering into the office.* This sentence is grammatical, but not as good as Sentence 1.  I think the comma after "Slowly" can be omitted.  Try *Slowly he entered the office*.
3. *Slowly, into the office was he entering.*  Grammatical, perhaps, but extremely awkward; and it remains awkward if you write "into the office he was entering".  I would not use this sentence.
4. *Into the office, slowly, was he entering.*  This sentence too is grammatical but extremely awkward, and I wouldn't use this one or its variant "...he was entering" either.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make inversion sound less awkward, let me first make your example "invertible":

> (1) *None other than Donald Trump was entering the office slowly.*

Note that I have changed 'he' into 'none other than Donald Trump' and removed 'into', and that I have used the term 'inversion' instead of 'fronting'.

> (2) *Entering the office slowly was none other than Donald Trump.*
>
> (3) *Slowly entering the office was none other than Donald Trump.*

I think either (2) or (3) is better than (1).